# Locating Russian town named Dobrows from 1902 passenger list?

Tags: russia

My great grandfather (named Adam Tyl on the passenger list) departed from Antwerp, Belgium 15, Feb. 1902 and arrived New York 22, Feb 1902.

The passenger list says he came from the town Dombrows Russia. I’m trying to locate this on a map but can't find the location. Could the town's name be Dombrowskistraße?

Comment: Hi, Cheryl, I'm editing this to make the content match the title and prevent it from being closed as too broad. Please take a moment to read our help at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help to understand how things work around here.

Comment: Hi Cheryl, welcome to Genealogy & Family History:SE. _Dombrowskistraße_ would normally be "Dombrowski Street", or something similar. I know that reading old handwriting can be tricky. Can you attach an image from the passenger list showing the town name to your question?

Comment: @pnuts Apparently ([Russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Донбасс_(топоним)#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), Donbass as a single word got into common usage only in 1917-1922.

Comment: Dombrowski is a double transliteration (from Polish to Russian then to English) of a Polish last name Dabrowski. So the town (if it's really the town) must be somewhere in Poland. As already said, Dombrowskistrasse is a street name. Dabrowa means "forest" in Polish, so there should be many toponyms like that as well.